# adjusting google lens zoom bars using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to maximize the zoom for full image search rather than just some areas on google lens. I have identified the element to hold and drag but the cursor does not point to the correct coordinates revealed by selenium. for example

```
topLeftElement = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[data-corner-type="1"]')
print(topLeftElement.location) # {'x': 535, 'y': 424}
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(topLeftElement,400,200).perform()
```

And i get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to move it slightly, for example `(topLeftElement,540,430)` and see what happens and then play with this numbers to get what you want? Don't forget to play with negative and small numbers like `(topLeftElement,-10,-5)` and `(topLeftElement,10,5)`

Comment: @EugenyOkulik thank you. It worked. Your comment made me understand how offset works.